# Where can I find Creative Commons science fiction suitable for use in fanfic?

Tags: fan-fiction

And other than public domain science fiction, how can I track down Creative Commons science fiction that is safe for re-mixing, i.e. fan fic?

Comment: This more aptly belongs on http://Writers.StackExchange.com since the scifi part doesn't really matter to the question

Comment: @eight I think this one is OK, considering we've got much bigger problems to tackle on this site

Comment: Many authors have pro-fanfic policies, and are fine as long as you don't try to sell your fanfic. You may not need PD/CC licensing.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise - he has specifically asked about **sci-fi** CC licenses.

Comment: If this belongs on another SE, then flag it so the mods can migrate it there, don't VTC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at Cory Doctorow's website [Craphound](http://craphound.com/) he releases all of his stories under Creative Commons Licenses, for instance "[With a Little Help](http://craphound.com/walh/e-book/browse-all-versions)" is released under [(CC BY-NC-SA 3.0)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

[Charles Stross](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/index.html) has also released some of his work under similar terms, there are details [here](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/online-fiction-by-charles-stro.html).

Comment: N.B. Charles Stross' FAQ on his (draft) [Fanfic policy](http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2010/05/faq-fanfic.html).

Comment: CC-BY-NC-SA should be reasonable Safe For Fanfic, but it should be stressed that *not all CC licenses fit the bill*.  Also, the NC provision is deliberately defined in a [much broader way](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/NonCommercial_interpretation) than you would expect.  Charities, for example, do not get any kind of blanket exemption.

Answer (score 8):

I created a universe a while back called Time Bridge. This was before CC existed or was at least popular. It was a world-building effort centered around a few periods all focused on a big time machine in space. The machine functioned on crap science, however, everything else in the world was meant to be Hard SF.

I don't know if any of it still exists. It wasn't very popular and aside from a few role-players and artists, I was the only person working on it. Still, remnants should be out there, maybe via the Wayback machine. Who knows.

I can try to dig it up and re-post it somewhere if anyone wants. Say if I get 20 upvotes on a comment I add to this answer.

Comment: upvote this if I should bother digging this crusty old world up.

Comment: I'm a cultural pack rat. Everything anyone ever writes should be preserved forever. Geocities going down was like the burning of the libraries at Alexandria.

Answer (score 2):

The [Dryden Experiment](https://web.archive.org/web/20140510000931/http://www.thedrydenexperiment.com/) is an entirely Creative Commons 3.0 driven universe.

Answer (score 0):

The universe I created in Blaze Master Mysterium of the Universe is safe for use in your fanfictions, if you like my stories feel free to use the world and settings, I am a little attached to the main character though, but feel free to use the rest, just credit me on the ideas you use.

Comment: Hi there. Even if I don't know the work I'm guessing this is indeed an answer; however for the record, depending on how much more you may want to talk about the universe you created, I suggest you take a look at [our guidelines on self-promotion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/promotion). You might as well be interested in taking the [tour] and browsing the [help]. Welcome to the site!